# How to stop auto update of Chrome Driver with Chrome plug in on Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have Selenium Grid 3.12.0 running on Jenkins with one node. Jenkins also has Chrome Driver Plug in installed. When i run my test i am getting error **session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74**. I download ChromeDriver 73 and place it in the driver folder. Run the test, everything works fine. Rerun the test, Chrome Plug in download he latest driver Chrome 74 and gets the same error.

*How can i disable auto downloading of latest Chrome driver?*

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 file path:_ C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update

Just rename the the file name of GoogleUpdate.exe to any name.

Comment: Chrome driver is auto downloading latest Chrome driver, not the Chrome browser